# Microsoft.AspNet.Identity Source Code Availability

Tags: .net, owin, katana

Can anybody tell me, where I can find source code of Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core and Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework packages?

Comment: At this moment a markdown at [the ASP.NET Identity project page](https://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Readme.markdown) says:

"Microsoft ASP.NET Identity 

At present, the ASP.NET Identity framework code is not public and therefore will not be published on this site. However, we are planning to change that, and as soon as we are able, the code will be published in this repository. In the meantime, the site will be used as a single point for tracking issues, hosting discussions, and providing links to documentation."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET source codes are also on GitHub for a while, including Identity;
https://github.com/aspnet/Identity

Edit: As @BrockAllen already pointed out, this is the version that will be published with vNext, not the source code of the current version (2.1) or lower.

Comment: This is v3 of ASP.NET Identity (which is nice that they finally have put something public). v1 and v2 where never OSS'd for some reason.

Answer (score 7):

It's not currently open source.

Answer (score 0):

Since this post, MS did open source it, and you can view that code here: 
https://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com

Note this is Identity 2, and is being replaced by Identity 3 and ASP.NET Core.  Still, if you need to see something in v2, this is easier than decompiling it...